# View to expand its own width based on children count

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

### The Question

Title says it all really, what I am trying to do is get the views width (once its been calculated) and times it by x to create "Pages" of tiles. This will then sit inside a `scrollview` so we can navigate left and right.

To do this I am using a custom view called `WrapLayout`, this does most of the work for me. I have modified it to try and override its width with the width I calculate myself (`width * pagecount`).

The main method I have focused on is `OnMeasure`, I believe this is the correct method to override for the situation.

```
protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
{
    var pageCount = (Children.Count / (Rows * 3)) + (Children.Count % (Rows * 3) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    if (HeightRequest > 0)
        heightConstraint = Math.Min(heightConstraint, HeightRequest);
    double internalHeight = double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, heightConstraint);
    if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(widthConstraint) && double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint))
    {
        return new SizeRequest(Size.Zero, Size.Zero);
    }

    var deviceWidth = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
    return new SizeRequest(new Size(deviceWidth * pageCount, internalHeight));
}
```

So I am using the override to size the view to `deviceWidth * pageCount`, this works apart from using the device width is not what I want, it should use its own calculated width so this view can be used without it stretching full device width.

**How can I get the width of the view after Xamarin has worked it out and override that value to replace it with my own to cause the view to be x times as big?**

I understand this is a big question so please feel free to comment if I have missed any key information.

**Note:** If there is a good answer on this I will give a bounty out when I am able. This is driving me crazy!

### Expected Results Demo

*As requested in the comments.* You can see the tiles are scaled correctly and the view has expanded its width to allow 6 tiles per view. This demo was created using the code in this post (using the device width, not the view width).

[image: Demo]

---

### The Code

This will be a lot of code as its a custom view so please bear with me, I will put this at the end of the post to keep the question shorter:

#### RepeatableWrapLayout

```
public class RepeatableWrapLayout : WrapLayoutSimple
{
    public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof (IEnumerable), typeof (RepeatableWrapLayout), null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: ItemsChanged);
    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTemplate), typeof (DataTemplate), typeof (RepeatableWrapLayout), default (DataTemplate), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        var control = (RepeatableWrapLayout)bindable;
        //when to occur propertychanged earlier ItemsSource than ItemTemplate, raise ItemsChanged manually
        if (newValue != null && control.ItemsSource != null && !control.doneItemSourceChanged)
        {
            ItemsChanged(bindable, null, control.ItemsSource);
        }
    }

    );
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static BindableProperty ItemTapCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemTapCommand), typeof (ICommand), typeof (RepeatableWrapLayout), default (ICommand), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanged: ItemTapCommandChanged);
    /// <summary>
    /// Command invoked when it tapped a item.
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand ItemTapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(ItemTapCommandProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemTapCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private bool doneItemSourceChanged = false;
    private static void ItemTapCommandChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (RepeatableWrapLayout)bindable;
        if (oldValue != newValue && control.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            UpdateCommand(control);
        }
    }

    private static void ItemsChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (RepeatableWrapLayout)bindable;
        // when to occur propertychanged earlier ItemsSource than ItemTemplate, do nothing.
        if (control.ItemTemplate == null)
        {
            control.doneItemSourceChanged = false;
            return;
        }

        control.doneItemSourceChanged = true;
        IEnumerable newValueAsEnumerable;
        try
        {
            newValueAsEnumerable = newValue as IEnumerable;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        var oldObservableCollection = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (oldObservableCollection != null)
        {
            oldObservableCollection.CollectionChanged -= control.OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }

        var newObservableCollection = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (newObservableCollection != null)
        {
            newObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += control.OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
        }

        control.Children.Clear();
        if (newValueAsEnumerable != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in newValueAsEnumerable)
            {
                var view = CreateChildViewFor(control.ItemTemplate, item, control);
                control.Children.Add(view);
            }
        }

        if (control.ItemTapCommand != null)
        {
            UpdateCommand(control);
        }

        control.UpdateChildrenLayout();
        control.InvalidateLayout();
    }

    private static void UpdateCommand(RepeatableWrapLayout control)
    {
        foreach (var view in control.Children)
        {
            view.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer{Command = control.ItemTapCommand, CommandParameter = view.BindingContext, });
        }
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var invalidate = false;
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
        {
            this.Children.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
            var item = e.NewItems[e.NewStartingIndex];
            var view = CreateChildViewFor(this.ItemTemplate, item, this);
            if (ItemTapCommand != null)
            {
                view.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer{Command = ItemTapCommand, CommandParameter = item, });
            }

            this.Children.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, view);
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; ++i)
                {
                    var item = e.NewItems[i];
                    var view = CreateChildViewFor(this.ItemTemplate, item, this);
                    if (ItemTapCommand != null)
                    {
                        view.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer{Command = ItemTapCommand, CommandParameter = item, });
                    }

                    this.Children.Insert(i + e.NewStartingIndex, view);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                this.Children.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            this.Children.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        if (invalidate)
        {
            this.UpdateChildrenLayout();
            this.InvalidateLayout();
        }
    }

    private View CreateChildViewFor(object item)
    {
        this.ItemTemplate.SetValue(BindableObject.BindingContextProperty, item);
        return (View)this.ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
    }

    private static View CreateChildViewFor(DataTemplate template, object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        var selector = template as DataTemplateSelector;
        if (selector != null)
        {
            template = selector.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }

        //Binding context
        template.SetValue(BindableObject.BindingContextProperty, item);
        return (View)template.CreateContent();
    }
}
```

#### WrapLayoutSimple

```
public class WrapLayoutSimple : Layout<View>
{
    Dictionary<Size, LayoutData> layoutDataCache = new Dictionary<Size, LayoutData>();
#region Props
    public static readonly BindableProperty RowsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Rows", typeof (int), typeof (WrapLayout), 2, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
    //((WrapTestLayout)bindable).InvalidateLayout();
    }

    );
    public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Columns", typeof (int), typeof (WrapLayout), 3, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
    // ((WrapTestLayout)bindable).InvalidateLayout();
    }

    );
    public static readonly BindableProperty ColumnSpacingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ColumnSpacing", typeof (double), typeof (WrapLayout), 0.00, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
    //((WrapTestLayout)bindable).InvalidateLayout();
    }

    );
    public static readonly BindableProperty RowSpacingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("RowSpacing", typeof (double), typeof (WrapLayout), 0.00, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
    //((WrapTestLayout)bindable).InvalidateLayout();
    }

    );
    public static readonly BindableProperty PagePaddingProperty = BindableProperty.Create("RowSpacing", typeof (Thickness), typeof (WrapLayout), new Thickness(0), propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
    //((WrapTestLayout)bindable).InvalidateLayout();
    }

    );
    public double ColumnSpacing
    {
        set
        {
            SetValue(ColumnSpacingProperty, value);
        }

        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(ColumnSpacingProperty);
        }
    }

    public double RowSpacing
    {
        set
        {
            SetValue(RowSpacingProperty, value);
        }

        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(RowSpacingProperty);
        }
    }

    public int Rows
    {
        set
        {
            SetValue(RowsProperty, value);
        }

        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(RowsProperty);
        }
    }

    public int Columns
    {
        set
        {
            SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
        }

        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
        }
    }

    public Thickness PagePadding
    {
        set
        {
            SetValue(PagePaddingProperty, value);
        }

        get
        {
            return (Thickness)GetValue(PagePaddingProperty);
        }
    }

#endregion
    public WrapLayoutSimple()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        var pageCount = (Children.Count / (Rows * 3)) + (Children.Count % (Rows * 3) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        if (HeightRequest > 0)
            heightConstraint = Math.Min(heightConstraint, HeightRequest);
        double internalHeight = double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, heightConstraint);
        if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(widthConstraint) && double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint))
        {
            return new SizeRequest(Size.Zero, Size.Zero);
        }

        var deviceWidth = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
        return new SizeRequest(new Size(deviceWidth * pageCount, internalHeight));
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        var PageCount = (Children.Count / (Rows * 3)) + (Children.Count % (Rows * 3) > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        var pageWidth = width / PageCount;
        LayoutData layoutData = GetLayoutData(pageWidth, height);
        if (layoutData.VisibleChildCount == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        double xChild = x;
        double yChild = y;
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int page = 0;
        int itemsPerPage = Rows * 3;
        foreach (View child in Children)
        {
            if (!child.IsVisible)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // New page
            if (count % itemsPerPage == 0 & count != 0)
            {
                // Add a page on
                page++;
                // Reset the Y so we start from the top again
                yChild = y;
            }

            count++;
            // A check for a guff width, if not use the good stuff.
            // Width * page will get it to the right width
            double xLocation;
            if (Double.IsInfinity(pageWidth))
                xLocation = 0;
            else
                xLocation = (pageWidth * page);
            LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, new Rectangle(new Point(xChild + xLocation, yChild), layoutData.CellSize));
            Debug.WriteLine("Adding child x: {0} y: {1} page: {2}", xChild + xLocation, yChild, page);
            // Reset for Second row if we hit our col limit
            if (++column == layoutData.Columns)
            {
                // Reset col
                column = 0;
                // Add row
                row++;
                // Reset the x so we start fromt he x start again (start of new row)
                xChild = x;
                // Add the height ready for the next placement (a row down)
                yChild += layoutData.CellSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                // Add the width ready for the next placement
                xChild += layoutData.CellSize.Width;
            }
        }
    }

    LayoutData GetLayoutData(double width, double height)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Page Width: " + width);
        Size size = new Size(width, height);
        // Check if cached information is available.
        if (layoutDataCache.ContainsKey(size))
        {
            return layoutDataCache[size];
        }

        int visibleChildCount = 0;
        Size maxChildSize = new Size();
        LayoutData layoutData = new LayoutData();
        // Enumerate through all the children.
        foreach (View child in Children)
        {
            // Skip invisible children.
            if (!child.IsVisible)
                continue;
            // Count the visible children.
            visibleChildCount++;
            // Get the child's requested size.
            SizeRequest childSizeRequest = child.Measure(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity);
            // Accumulate the maximum child size.
            maxChildSize.Width = Math.Max(maxChildSize.Width, childSizeRequest.Request.Width);
            maxChildSize.Height = Math.Max(maxChildSize.Height, childSizeRequest.Request.Height);
        }

        if (visibleChildCount != 0)
        {
            // Now maximize the cell size based on the layout size.
            Size cellSize = new Size();
            if (Double.IsPositiveInfinity(width))
            {
                cellSize.Width = maxChildSize.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                cellSize.Width = width / Columns;
            }

            if (Double.IsPositiveInfinity(height))
            {
                cellSize.Height = maxChildSize.Height;
            }
            else
            {
                cellSize.Height = height / Rows;
            }

            layoutData = new LayoutData(visibleChildCount, cellSize, Rows, Columns);
        }

        layoutDataCache.Add(size, layoutData);
        Debug.WriteLine("Cell Width: " + layoutData.CellSize.Width + " Height: " + layoutData.CellSize.Height);
        return layoutData;
    }

    protected override void InvalidateLayout()
    {
        base.InvalidateLayout();
        // Discard all layout information for children added or removed.
        layoutDataCache.Clear();
    }

    protected override void OnChildMeasureInvalidated()
    {
        base.OnChildMeasureInvalidated();
        // Discard all layout information for child size changed.
        layoutDataCache.Clear();
    }
}
```

#### XAML

```
<l:RepeatableWrapLayout
                x:Name="rwl"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <l:RepeatableWrapLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">
                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </l:RepeatableWrapLayout.ItemTemplate>
</l:RepeatableWrapLayout>
```

Using all I have provided you should be able to build this yourself to test if needed.

Comment: having an image of expected result or gif helps us visually understand the issue

Comment: @LeRoy I have updated my question with the expected result, please let me know if there is anything else I can add to make this a clearer question.

Comment: I don't see why you need the parent's width. In the `OnMeasure` method, just say that you need infinite width. You can do so just by relaying the widthConstraint

Comment: @Daniel That will make it the parents width (for me device width), I need to multiple that by `x` to make it bigger then its parent (scrollview) so it will be scrollable in pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a bit of a work around for now, it seems to work quite well so will be testing with this version.

I have setup a new property on the `wraplayout` to accept in its parents width, since in this case the parent is a scrollview we use that views width and pass it to the `wraplayout` like so.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty ParentWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ParentWidth",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(WrapLayout),
    0.00,
    propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) =>
    {
        ((RepeatableWrapLayout)bindable).SetNewWidth();
    });

public double ParentWidth
{
    set { SetValue(ParentWidthProperty, value); }
    get { return (double)GetValue(ParentWidthProperty); }
}
```

Using this we can trigger an event when the property changes and set the width for the `wraplayout`. I have a few checks in here to stop it from tiggering before it needs to.

```
double oldParentWidth;
public void SetNewWidth()
{
    var pageCount = (Children.Count / (Rows * 3)) + (Children.Count % (Rows * 3) > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    if (ParentWidth > 0 && ParentWidth != oldParentWidth)
    {
        oldParentWidth = ParentWidth;
        WidthRequest = ParentWidth * pageCount;
    }
}
```

The XAML now looks like this to bind the parents width to our newly created property.

```
<Controls:RepeatableWrapLayout ParentWidth="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=parentScrollView} ,Path=Width}" ...>
   ...
</Controls:RepeatableWrapLayout>
```